# Sell products at purchase price (Magento)

Tags: magento, coupon

I've created a webshop in Magento, where the owner also wants to order products for himself at the purchase price.
So just to be correct with the stock, he would buy products for himself at the price, he bought it himself.

I thought this could be done with a coupon or something, but I cannot find to use the purchase price in the promo codes.

Does anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a new price group in: Customers > Customer Groups in admin.  Assign this particular user to that price group and go and add the group price to the products.